# Custom jQuery widget doesn't work on Heroku

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, heroku

I have created a small jQuery widget using [the widget factory pattern](http://ajpiano.com/widgetfactory/#slide1). It works fine locally, but when pushing the code to Heroku it doesn't work anymore.

If I create a small test app like the following:

```
(function ($, undefined) {
$.ui.mytest = {
  _create: function () {
      alert('test');
  },
  destroy: function () {
      // if using jQuery UI 1.8.x
      $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
      // if using jQuery UI 1.9.x
      //this._destroy();
  },
  options:{}
};
$.widget("ui.mytest", $.ui.mytest);


})(jQuery);
```

It will print an alert locally, but in production, when the assets have been compiled, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined application-2ecb4e7c4dcb5be5c5d9884cdb6c266c.js:14
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'mytest'
```

The wierd thing is that I in production can call `$.ui.mytest` on my console and it actually exists. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including any other jQuery UI widgets in your dev env but not in production as if you've not got any other widgets using the UI namespace before you try to define `$.ui.mytest` then it'll error because `$.ui` won't be defined. The namespace is defined only once you've called `$.widget`.

It would make a lot more sense for you to pass that object directly into `$.widget()` as the second argument as you're basically trying to store what will become the widgets prototype under what will eventually become the constructors namespace. e.g:

```
$.widget('ui.mytest', {
    _create: function () {
        alert('tesst');   
    }
});
```

The above will automatically create a constructor function that looks like this:

```
new $.ui.mytest(options, element);
```

But it's unlikely you'd instantiate it directly like that because the widget factory also defines a jQuery plugin which is a wrapper around the above.